# SublimeText XML completions file

Tags: autocomplete, xml, sublime-text-3, sublime-text, tab-completion

I apparently can't get autocompletion to work in my XML files.
Here is my `xml.sublime-completions` file, which I added to the User folder:

```
{
  "scope": "text.xml",
  "completions":
  [
    {
      "trigger": "t",
      "contents": "<Text id="$1"><![CDATA[$0]]></Text>"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now typing t-<tab> in XML file only results in <t></t>:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<t></t>
```

How to I even start debugging this?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out a little more difficult than I anticipated.

1. I had Emmet package installed. Emmet has own autocompletion support, but I did not manage to make it spit out the `<![CDATA[...]]>` sequence that I needed.
2. So I disabled Emmet's autocompletion for xml scope by inserting the following in `Emmet.sublime-settings`:

   `{ "disable_tab_abbreviations_for_scopes": "text.xml" }`
3. Sublime snippets are themselves using <![CDATA[...]]> syntax for the replacement strings. Doh.  [<![CDATA[...]] tags can't be nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223652/is-there-a-way-to-escape-a-cdata-end-token-in-xml). It does not allow multiple CDATA inside 'content' tags either.
4. Now the desired autocompletion works well in good old xml.sublime-completions:

   `{ "scope": "text.xml",
      "completions": [
         { "trigger": "t",
           "contents": "<Text id="$1"><![CDATA[$0]]>/Text>"
         }
       ]
    }`